# Materialized view locks

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view, materialized-views

Currently, when we refresh a materialized view on our master DB sometimes we face locks.

Is it possible to have a materialized view on a read-only replica and run the materialized view only there? Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a materialized view only on a standby server, because you cannot create anything there.

If you use `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY`, the view will only be locked for a short time. If that causes problems, make sure that your transactions are short.